# Python - add column and calculate value based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

I'm having a dataset that looks as follows:

```
data = {'Year':[2012, 2013, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2013],
        'Quarter':[2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1],
        'ID':['CH7744', 'US4652', 'CA47441', 'CH1147', 'DE7487', 'US5174'],
        'MC':[3348.22, 8542.55, 11851.2, 15718.1, 29914.7, 8731.78 ],
        'PB': [2.74, 0.95, 1.57, 2.13, 0.54, 5.32]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

Now what I aim to do is to add a new column "SMB" and calculate it as follows:

- Subset data based on year and quarter, e. g. get all values where year = 2012, and quarter = 2
- Sort the subset based on column MC and split it based on the size into small and big (0.5 Quantile)
- If the value in MC is lower than 0.5 quantile add value "small" to the newly created column "SMB", if it is higher than the 0.5 quantile add value "big"
- Repeat the process for all rows where quarter = 2
- For all other rows add np.nan

so the output should look like that

```
data = {'Year':[2012, 2013, 2012, 2013, 2014, 2013],
        'Quarter':[2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 1],
        'ID':['CH7744', 'US4652', 'CA47441', 'CH1147', 'DE7487', 'US5174'],
        'MC':[3348.22, 8542.55, 11851.2, 15718.1, 29914.7, 8731.78 ],
        'PB': [2.74, 0.95, 1.57, 2.13, 0.54, 5.32],
        'SMB': ['Small', 'Small', 'Big', 'Big', np.NaN, np.NaN]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

I tried to create a loop but I was unable to properly merge it back into the previous dataframe as I need other quarter values for further calculation. Using below code I sort of achieved what I wanted to have, but I had to merge back the data into the original dataset.
I'm sure there is a much nicer way on how to achieve this.

```
# Quantile 0.5 for MC sorting (small & big)
smbQuantile = 0.5
Years = df['Year'].unique()
dataframes_list = []

# Calculate Small and Big and merge back into dataFrame
for i in Years:
    df_temp = df.loc[(df_sb['Year'] == i) & (df['Quarter'] == 2)]
    df_temp['SMB'] = ''
    #Assign factor size based on market cap
    df_temp.SMB[df_temp.MKT_CAP <= df_temp.MKT_CAP.quantile(smbQuantile)] = 'Small'
    df_temp.SMB[df_temp.MKT_CAP >= df_temp.MKT_CAP.quantile(smbQuantile)] = 'Big'
    dataframes_list.append(df_temp)

df = pd.concat(dataframes_list)
```

Comment: Have you heard of `df.apply`? If you define a function that takes a series and some additional parameters (like the quantiles you fine), you can create a column relatively nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`groupby.rank`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.rank.html) and [`groupby.transform('size')`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) combined with [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
g = df.groupby(['Year', 'Quarter'])['MC']

df['SMB'] = np.select([g.rank(pct=True).le(0.5),
                       g.transform('size').ge(2)],
                      ['Small', 'Big'], np.nan)
```

output:

```
   Year  Quarter       ID        MC    PB    SMB
0  2012        2   CH7744   3348.22  2.74  Small
1  2013        2   US4652   8542.55  0.95  Small
2  2012        2  CA47441  11851.20  1.57    Big
3  2013        2   CH1147  15718.10  2.13    Big
4  2014        3   DE7487  29914.70  0.54    nan
5  2013        1   US5174   8731.78  5.32    nan
```

Comment: Thanks so much, this works with this example dataset. However it doesn't with the one I'm working with... so I need to to find out what's really done whithin the np.select, as somehow g.size().ge2 returns always True within my dataFrame I'm working with:
`
g.size().ge(2)
Out  [62]: 
Year  Quarter
2012  1          True
      2          True
      3          True
      4          True
2013  1          True
      2          True
      3          True
      4          True
`

Comment: Can you provide an updated counterexample ?

Comment: Sorry I'm struggling a bit to reproduce without providing the original dataset.. I need some more time to come up with that.. The fact is that the dataset is much larger and g.size() looks as follows:

```
Year  Quarter
2012  1          1996
      2          2000
      3          1999
      4          2002
2013  1          2001
      2          2015
      3          2010
      4          2019
2014  1          2019
      2          2038
      3          2041
      4          2045
2015  1          2043
      2          2043
      3          2041
      4          2045
```